# Netty channels lifecycle

Tags: java, http, netty

After reading netty guides and examples I still have some questions:

My app communicates with multiple third party endpoints. For this purpose I am using http client implemented with Netty.
So basically the flow is the following

1. Http call to execute operation 1
   --some business logic procesing--
2. Http call to execute operation 2
   --some business logic procesing--
3. Http call to execute operation 3
   --some business logic procesing--

Every operation is executed in different thread.

Q1: Do I need to create and close the channel for every new request or I just need to reuse the same channel per endoint and use it until is available.

Q2: As I am communicating with multiple systems I suppose that I must use some kind of channels pooling?

Q3: If I have to reuse the channel, how to handle closed channel. Let's say I have multiple threads wanting to trigger http request to the same channel and the first one fails because connection is closed. Do I need to coordinate/lock threads to wait for creation of new channel and allowing to proceed only after new channel is open again?

Q4: When I will want to have more than one channel per endpoint? (Perhaps if I want to utilize better processor cores?)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good tutorial that lays out how it works under the hood. [Netty IO](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/netty/index.html). You only need to create some resources once. The event loop group which is the threading can be reused. Essentially you do not really need to worry about the channel if you have it setup correctly. Just use the channel to read and write from, or use handlers to do the work. When done, close the channel but do not shutdown the EventLoopGroup, because you'll need to give it to another bootstrap.  You can use channel pooling if you will be making lots of connections, but it is normally not necessary.

I also recommend this guide which will answer you other questions. It tells you how to write to the channel better from other threads, ect. [Netty Best Practices](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html)

Your questions other then that are very case specific. Why not set up a test main method or a test unit and try it out yourself after running through those two links if not another tutorial or two? Netty can be a complex beast and you can pretty much do anything you want, but it really provides everything you need at a entry networking level without the need for much complexity. [Another one for the road](https://medium.com/coderscorner/netty-fundamentals-c17913ab9165), also check out their samples [Examples from Netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example). Their samples represent the most common use cases and basic level of networking protocols.